# Node.js path error

Tags: node.js, express

Under my server.js i have the following

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
 res.sendFile('index.html');
});

app.get('/report', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile('report.html');
});
```

When i start the server and render on http://localhost:8000 i am able to see index.html, but on http://localhost:8000/report i am unable to render report.html and instead i get an path error **path must be absolute or specify root to res.sendFile**

My directory structure is

```
public
   index.html
   report.html
```

Why i am getting this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `express.static()` will serve up `index.html` when just `/` is requested (see [reference in the doc](https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static#index)).  So, your `index.html` is being served by the `express.static()` middleware, not by your `app.get('/', ...)` route.

So, both your `app.get()` routes would likely have the exact same issue.  The first one just isn't being called because your `express.static()` configuration is already handling that request and sending back `index.html`.

The `/report` route is not being handled by `express.static()` because `report` is not the same request as `report.html`.  Thus, the middleware does not handle the request so then your misconfigured `app.get('/report', ...)` handler is invoked and you get the error about it being misconfigured.

This should be all you need:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/report', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/report.html");
});

app.listen(8080);
```

---

Or, you can use the path module and join the pieces with `path.join()`:

```
var path = require("path");
```

And, then serve the file with this:

```
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'report.html'));
```

In my own sample nodejs app, either of these `res.sendFile()` options work.

Comment: i did try this res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/report.html') but that outputs a Cannot GET /report

Comment: I'm on my phone now, but I wonder if it helps to change the route to `/report/`?

Comment: this did it res.sendFile('report.html',{root: __dirname + '/public/'});

Comment: @user3750842 - when I try it myself, either of these work: `    `res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'report.html'));` or `res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/report.html");`.

Answer (score 1):

npm install path

then, you have to specify the root path:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
 res.sendFile('index.html');
});

app.get('/report', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile('report.html', { root: path.join(__dirname, './public') });
});

app.listen(8000);
```

Comment: That's weird. I just tried it on a separate linux and windows and works great on both. Do you have path module installed? I have a server.js in the root folder, and the index.html, report.html in the public folder. The public folder is next to the server.js.

Comment: yep i have a the path module installed but when i did this  res.sendFile('report.html',{root: __dirname + '/public/'}); it worked